# Storing array of Components(panel.getComponents()) to Array List

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcomponent

I have 3 checkboxes and planning to add more and I need to determine if it is checked or not. So what I did was to put them in an ArrayList of JCheckBox. By the way, I'm using `SMALLINT` apache derby data type on which ill use `preparedStatement.getBoolean()`;

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> homeCbxs = new ArrayList<>();
homeCbxs.add(updateUserNameCheckBox); // 0
homeCbxs.add(updatePasswordCheckBox); // 1
homeCbxs.add(updatePhotoCheckBox); // 2

int x = 0; 
for(JCheckBox cb : homeCbxs){
    Boolean bool;
    bool = cb.isSelected();
    //preparedStatement here, ps.setInt(x,bool)
    x++;
}
```

I thought maybe I can use the `getComponents()` method which returns an array of components so I can get all the check boxes inside a panel.

Maybe like,

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> homeCbxs = homePermssionsCheckBoxPanel.getComponents();
```

Instead of adding them one by one,

```
homeCbxs.add(updateUserNameCheckBox); // 0
homeCbxs.add(updatePasswordCheckBox); // 1
homeCbxs.add(updatePhotoCheckBox); // 2
```

However, the problem is `ArrayList<JComponents>` won't accept arrays. I get an error message that **incompatible types: Component[] cannot be converted `ArrayList<JCheckBox>`**

Do you have any suggestions? Any workaround to cast or do some conversions. I'm just trying to shorten the lines of codes. :D

Also, I would like to ask if `getComponents()` assigns 0 as first index of it's array.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own utility method to get the components.

```
public List<Component> getComponentsAsList (Container cont){
    return Stream.of(cont.getComponents())
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then, you just have to not forget to cast them to `JCheckBox` to check if they're checked or not.

```
List<Component> list = getComponentsAsList(homePermssionsCheckBoxPanel);

for(Component c : list){
    if (!(c instanceof JCheckBox)) continue;
    if (((JCheckBox)c).isSelected()){
        // doStuff
    }
}
```

---

### [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7)

```
public List<Component> getComponentsAsList (Container cont){
    List<Component> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Component c : cont.getComponents()) {
        tmp.add(c);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Might make sense to check if `c` is of type `JCheckBox` first, depending on if `homePermssionsCheckBoxPanel` contains any other components like buttons.

Comment: @Marv Indeed, I'll add it.

Comment: @Yassin Hajaj Thank you. This takes less codes. And this is what I want to do. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @YassinHajaj By the way this works well with Java 8 but when I tried it on java 1.7, it didn't work. It shows an error on Stream.of(...)  and it looks like it won't recognize it. Do you have any suggestion to make it work on Java 1.7? Thanks.

Comment: @YassinHajaj This is very helpful. My knowledge is actually limited to ArrayLists and Lists and I just started digging with Collections and Sets when I saw your syntax. I appreciate the suggestion for Java 7 because our team is on Java 7. Thanks. Plenty more things to learn.